# How to list all User Groups and Users

Tags: users

I'm nearly there on this one but could use some help. I want to list all User Groups, with all Users listed under each group. For bonus points, this all needs to be alphabetical (Group, then Users). Something like...

**User Group A**

- User Name A
- User Name B
- etc...

**User Group B**

- User Name A
- User Name B
- etc...

Here's what I have so far...

```
{% set userGroups = craft.userGroups.getAllGroups() %}

{% if userGroups|length %}
    {% for userGroup in userGroups %}
        <h2>{{ userGroup.name }}</h2>
        {# list all users for this group #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I just can't figure out how to loop through users for a userGroup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
{% set userGroups = craft.userGroups.getAllGroups() %}

{% if userGroups|length %}
    {% for userGroup in userGroups %}
        <h2>
            {{ userGroup.name }}
        </h2>

        {% set users = craft.users.group(userGroup.handle) %}

        <ul>
        {% for user in users %}
            <li>
                {{ user.username }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're going for?

```
{% set userGroups = craft.users.getAllGroups().order('firstName ASC') %}

{% if userGroups|length %}
    {{ userGroups.group }}

    {% for userGroup in userGroups %}
        <h2>{{ userGroup.name }}</h2>
        {# list all users for this group #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This will output all of the Users in ABC order based on the `firstName` field.

Comment: Hi guys, and thanks. Nearly there but {{ userGroups.group }} outputs nothing.